# downmix stero to mono using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

After mixing this polish stereo to mono, the audio is broken (more or less silent):

```
ffmpeg -i http://doppelbauer.name/polish.wav -ac 1 -ar 16000 test.wav
```

How to mix left+right channel correctly?

Comment: Share the full log.

Comment: Open it in an audio editor to see if the theory is correct

Comment: I opened the video in an audio editor - with no result.

Comment: "No result" would be that there was no graphical representation of the sound… otherwise there is "some result".  I did it for you. It's not 'stereo' it's phase-inverted - plain to see if you did what I asked, open it in an audio editor & look at the waveforms. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmkdm.png

Comment: Rotating the phase of one side 180 degrees doesn't really help. It's so badly recorded it just really needs doing again, properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everything sounds normal through the speakers.

Comment: No it doesn't. It sounds out of phase.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It could be downmixed, if you can flip the phase of one side - but all you gain will be volume. You could do the same by discarding one side then turning the other up by 6dB. I'm afraid idk how to do this in ffmpeg.

Comment: For discarding one side then turning the other up by 6dB: `ffmpeg -i input -af "pan=mono|c0=c1,volume=6dB" output`. See [filter docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) and [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channels](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) for more info.